# Calling button function from user control

Tags: asp.net, function, button, user-controls, call

Previously , I has a default aspx page which include a main user control.

The main user control is user for dynamic load the menu item . For example **Contact person** and **sales order** .

When user click on **contact person** the content of the **contact person** is load from other sub user control .

[image]

**Default aspx front-end**

```
Here is the aspx page which include the main user control
     <div class="rightColumnModule2">
                                <asp:Panel ID="pnUserControl" runat="server">
                                        <uc2:SubMenuItem ID="MainMenuItem1" runat="server"/>
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </div>
```

**submenuitem back end code**

```
   //dynamic load other content of user control
  //I am using placeholder to load from other user control
        private void loadUserControl()
        {
            if (this.hfSelectSubItemURL.Value != "")
            {
                UserControl ucSimpleControl = LoadControl(this.hfSelectSubItemURL.Value) as UserControl;
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ucSimpleControl);
            }
        }
```

**ContactPersonList.ascx front-end**

```
div class="rightColumnModule2">


                            <div class="rightColumnModule2TitleContainer">
                                <table class="rightColumnModule2Table">

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="rightColumnModule2Title">
                                                Contact Person</div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                           <cc1:cusAcesslevelBtn ID="btncAdd" runat="server" aclType="Add" 
                                                CssClass="inputButonS" onclick="btncAdd_Click" Text="Add" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <!-- end of rightColumnModule2TitleContainer -->
                            <div id="Div2" class="rightColumnModule2Content" runat="server">


                                            <div class="rightColumnModule2ContentSub">
                                    <div class="rightColumnModule2TitleSub">
                                        System Information 

                                        </div>

                                        <table class="table100">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="tableVT" style="width: 49%">
                                                <table class="table100">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="rightColumnModule2DetailLabel" style="width: 30%">
                                                            Create by &nbsp; </td><td class="rightColumnModule2DetailColon" style="width: 5%">
                                                            : </td><td class="rightColumnModule2DetailValue" style="width: 65%">
                                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
                                                               ></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;<asp:Label
                                                                ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label></td></tr></table></td><td class="gapHori1" style="width: 2%">
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="tableVT" style="width: 49%">
                                                <table class="table100">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="rightColumnModule2DetailLabel" style="width: 30%">
                                                            Modify By </td><td class="rightColumnModule2DetailColon" style="width: 5%">
                                                            : </td><td class="rightColumnModule2DetailValue" style="width: 65%">
                                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;<asp:Label
                                                                ID="Label4" runat="server"></asp:Label></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>

                                                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>  <!-- end of rightColumnModule2Content -->
```

How can I call the Add button which come from ContactPersonList.ascx  in my default aspx page? Please guild me a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can have two approach:

1. using **FindControl** property:

   ```
    Button btn1 =UserControlID.FindControl("btn1") as Button;
    if(btn1 != null)
    {
      //your stuff with button
    }
   ```

   **OR**
2. You can directly call click event of UserControl button:

   UserControl Page:

   ```
   <asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="Button1" onclick="btn_Click" />
   ```

   Code Behind:

   ```
   public event EventHandler ButtonClick;
   protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     ButtonClick(sender, e);
   }
   ```

   Aspx page:

   ```
   <UC1:UC1 ID="UserControl1" runat="server" />
   ```

   Code behind:

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      UserControl1.ButtonClick += new EventHandler(UserControl1_ButtonClick);
   }

   protected void UserControl1_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Response.Write("this is usercontrol button event.");
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi , i want to know  about the 1st approach. Where should i use find control method? in the default page or wat?

Comment: For the 2nd approach. I not able to use UserControl1.ButtonClick += new EventHandler(UserControl1_ButtonClick . Because i am using placeholder to load the user control

Comment: 1st approach: in the default page. 2nd approach: you have to find usercontrol id.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. can you explain me why should i use public event EventHandler ButtonClick;
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ButtonClick(sender, e);
}